How to predict whether a query plan will involve the use of an index?
I am using the latest PostgreSQL docker image to create a local DB (on an Apple M1 Pro - MacOS Sonoma 14.5 machine). I create a table table0 with a single  column col0 within it, and fill it with random strings of 2 to 16 characters. I create a trigram-index on col0 and vacuum (analyze). Exact steps:
create table public.table0 (
    col0 varchar(25)
);

select setseed(0.12343);

insert into table0 (col0)
select substring(md5(random()::text), 1, (2 + (random() * 14))::int)
from generate_series(1, 12345678);

create extension pg_trgm;
create index col0_gin_trgm_idx on table0 using gin (col0 gin_trgm_ops);

vacuum (analyze) table0;

I examine the query plan for selecting 200 rows containing the string abc:
explain analyze
select * from table0 where col0 like '%abc%' limit 200;

Output, confirming that trigram index is not, but a sequential scan is used:
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..351.78 rows=200 width=10) (actual time=0.313..15.640 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on table0  (cost=0.00..216614.79 rows=123154 width=10) (actual time=0.312..15.620 rows=200 loops=1)
         Filter: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 115643
 Planning Time: 4.401 ms
 Execution Time: 15.841 ms
(6 rows)

However, if instead of searching for rows containing abc I search for rows containing bcd:
explain analyze
select * from table0 where col0 like '%bcd%' limit 200;

Then I get a different query plan, which now includes an index scan:
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.34..764.83 rows=200 width=10) (actual time=7.032..7.230 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.94 rows=1219 width=10) (actual time=7.031..7.220 rows=200 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%bcd%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=169
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=5.100..5.100 rows=21264 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%bcd%'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.521 ms
 Execution Time: 7.366 ms
(8 rows)

This setup might not be entirely reproducible on the first try, even though setseed(0.12343); is used, since analyze "collects statistics based on its own random selection of rows" (see second paragraph here). I recreated the above situation several times, and I never had to attempt the setup steps more than 4 times, so I hope it's easily reproducible, even though the code I provide is not entirely deterministic. (I removed and relaunched the docker container between attempts.)
This answer gives a basic explanation of why once the sequential scan and why sometimes the index scan is used. It also has 2 suggestions on how to discourage sequential scans: modifying random_page_cost and STATISTICS values.
I set random_page_cost to 1.1 (via ALTER DATABASE postgres SET random_page_cost = 1.1;). I also "raise the amount of statistics collected" by analyze (via ALTER TABLE table0 ALTER COLUMN col0 SET STATISTICS 1000;). After another vacuum (analyze) table0; I rerun:
explain analyze
select * from table0 where col0 like '%abc%' limit 200;

and this time the col0_gin_trgm_idx trigram index is indeed used. After this, I recreated the scenario above, and without modifying random_page_cost or STATISTICS I rerun vacuum (analyze) table0; - this also modified the behaviour and caused a switch from sequential scan to index scan. I believe this is due to the non-deterministic nature of statistics collected by analyze.
This time, instead of being able to trigger the use of the index (which I am able to do so now, mainly thanks to the mentioned answer), I would like to understand the details on how the decision is made between sequential scan and index scan. Ideally, I would like to be able to predict whether query:
explain analyze
select * from table0 where col0 like '%xyz%' limit 200;

will trigger an index scan or a sequential scan, knowing xyz, and anything related to database statistics or settings. Previously, in the context of a similar question, I was advised to check SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = ANY ( '{shared_buffers, effective_cache_size, random_page_cost, effective_io_concurrency, work_mem}'::text[]);. It returns (before modifying default settings):
           name           | setting 
--------------------------+---------
 effective_cache_size     | 524288
 effective_io_concurrency | 1
 random_page_cost         | 4
 shared_buffers           | 16384
 work_mem                 | 4096
(5 rows)

I think these values have an effect on the sequential scan vs index scan decision. I hope a function f with two possible outputs: sequential scan or index scan exists. I imagine f takes xyz, random_page_cost, statistics collected by analyze, etc as inputs. I would like to understand the list of inputs (ie what is etc?) and what f does with them.
How can I predict whether a query plan will involve the use of an index?

The LIKE operator uses the histogram_bounds array column from pg_stats to estimate the selectivity for that operator with the fixed pattern.  It uses this array as if it were a random sample of the table (which is not entirely correct to treat it that way, but nonetheless that is what it does).
Given your example dataset, that array is likely to have either 0 entries which match '%abc%', or 1, depending on how the random sample used by ANALYZE falls. If the array has one match, then it will estimate an selectivity of about 1/101.  If the array has zero matches, then it will initially estimate the selectivity of 0, but then later clamp it to 0.0001 before using it. (A few days ago I described this differently, but I've since reviewed the source code to clarify what was going on, see the source).  Depending on which of those things happens, it will do the seq scan or the index scan because it thinks either one or the other will be faster.
This explanation ignores the effect of most_common_vals and null_frac, which are used in general but I don't think they make much difference in your specific case.
To predict which will happen, you could inspect the array and count how many of its elements match %abc%:
select count(*), count(*) filter (where t like '%abc%')  
from pg_stats, unnest(histogram_bounds::text::text[]) t 
where attname='col0' and tablename='table0';

The output of this will depend on the random sample obtained the ANALYZE. It looks like the sample will contain 1/101 match about a quarter of the time and 0/101 match the rest of the time.
It is not clear what useful thing you can do with this, but your question seems to be driven more by curiosity than practicality.  (To turn this into a complete prediction would be a lot of work incorporating your planner settings, other catalog tables, etc., which would be an awful lot of work for something with no obvious practical application.)

Great, I tested this on a real life example, and it worked.

Jeff provided first-class insights how the query planner estimates.
As for the function you are wishing for: you already have it: EXPLAIN.
Any custom function we might come up with (after hard work trying to emulate much of the query planners functionality) could only come close to EXPLAIN at best. Because EXPLAIN is the source of truth.
If you really want a boolean answer to the question "Will this query use that index?", you can loop through EXPLAIN output in a function. Basically:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_query_uses_index(qry text, idx text)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   line text;
BEGIN
   FOR line in
      EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || qry
   LOOP
      IF line ~ idx THEN
         RETURN true;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN false;
END
$func$;

Call for your example:
SELECT f_query_uses_index($q$select * from table0 where col0 like '%bcd%' limit 200$q$
                        , 'col0_gin_trgm_idx')

Be aware that passing code is wide open to SQL injection and other problems. So this is only for trusted users.
That said, just looking at the EXPLAIN output will be best in most situations.
